# Create custom package with facade in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-facade

I am trying to develop a new Laravel package locally installed via Composer.

These are my steps:

- I install a new Laravel application with `composer create-project laravel/laravel my-application`
- I create a new directory in the root with the following content:

  `packages/randolf/custom-package/composer.json`

  ```json
  {
      "name": "randolf/custom-package",
      "description": "My new Custom Package",
      "type": "library",
      "license": "MIT",
      "require": {},
      "autoload": {
          "psr-4": {
              "Randolf\\CustomPackage\\" : "src/"
          }
      },
      "extra": {
          "laravel": {
              "providers": [
                  "Randolf\\CustomPackage\\CustomPackageServiceProvider"
              ],
              "aliases": {
                  "CustomPackage": "Randolf\\CustomPackage\\Facades"
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  `packages/randolf/custom-package/src/CustomPackage.php`

  ```php
  <?php

  namespace Randolf\CustomPackage;

  class CustomPackage
  {
      public function sayHi()
      {
          return "Hi from class!";
      }
  }
  ```

  `packages/randolf/custom-package/src/CustomPackageServiceProvider.php`

  ```php
  <?php

  namespace Randolf\CustomPackage;

  use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

  class CustomPackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
  {
      public function boot()
      {

      }

      public function register()
      {
          $this->app->bind('custom-package', function()
          {
              return new CustomPackage();
          });
      }
  }
  ```

  `packages/randolf/custom-package/src/Facades/CustomPackageFacade.php`

  ```php
  <?php

  namespace Randolf\CustomPackage\Facades;

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

  class CustomPackageFacade extends Facade
  {

      /**
      * Get the registered name of the component.
      *
      * @return string
      */
      protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'custom-package'; }
  }
  ```
- I add my package in Laravel with composer, adding the `repositories` key:
  `/composer.json`

  ```json
  "repositories": {
      "randolf/custom-package": {
          "type": "path",
          "url": "packages/randolf/custom-package",
          "options": {
              "symlink": true
          }
      }
  },
  "require": {
      ...
      "randolf/custom-package": "@dev"
  },
  ```
- I run `composer update` and the install, package discover and dump-autoload works correctly:

  ```sh
  Loading composer repositories with package information
  Updating dependencies
  Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking randolf/custom-package (dev-master)
  Writing lock file
  Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
  Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing randolf/custom-package (dev-master): Junctioning from packages/randolf/custom-package
  Generating optimized autoload files
  > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
  > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
  Discovered Package: facade/ignition
  Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
  Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
  Discovered Package: laravel/sail
  Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
  Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
  Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
  Discovered Package: randolf/custom-package
  Package manifest generated successfully.
  73 packages you are using are looking for funding.
  Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
  ```
- I create a route in `routes/web.php` to test the facade:

  ```php
  Route::get('/test-facade', function () {
      echo CustomPackage::sayHi();
  });
  ```

Result:
[image: laravel facade error]

Comment: you forgot to add the class name of your actual facade to the namespace where you are adding the alias in the composer.json file ... you aliased the namespace not the facade itself

Comment: ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️ Tested and working. If you reply as an answer, I will be able to accept it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Nice tutorial! But you're invoking your method `sayHi()` as static, so you need to define it as static: `public function sayHi()` ⇒ `public static function sayHi()`.

Comment: Why do you set `$this->app->bind` in your provider's `register()` method ? Not using it seems to work fine too...

Comment: @DevonDahon it´s a feature called `Facades` in Laravel. You can call non-static method as static methods. First bind a new instance of your class in the provider with a name (`custom-package` in this example). Then, create the Facade that return this same name (`CustomPackageFacade` and therefore the instance of your class) and finally, you register and Alias to the facade in your `composer.json`. Thus you call `CustomPackage::sayHi()` that it´s the same as `(new CustomPackage())->sayHi()`. More info: https://laravel.com/docs/master/facades

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the alias in the `composer.json` to point to the Facade instead of its namespace:

```
"CustomPackage": "Randolf\\CustomPackage\\Facades\\CustomPackageFacade"
```